# How to calculate velocity east, north up having lat/lng/alt/time?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

I have a certain values from a camera and wondering how the velocity east, north and up is calculated.

Here are the values

```
  GPSLatitude: 50.456102333333334
  GPSLongitude: 30.479830833333335
  GPSAltitude: 146.8000030517578
  VelocityEast: 0.6993362307548523
  VelocityNorth: 1.19965398311615
  VelocityUp: 0.0

  GPSLatitude: 50.456104833333335
  GPSLongitude: 30.479832166666665
  GPSAltitude: 146.60000610351562
  VelocityEast: 0.6831040978431702
  VelocityNorth: 1.421926498413086
  VelocityUp: 0.0
```

but when i am manually creating the velocities then they are different.

using `pymap3d` to get velocities.

```
lat0, lon0, h0 = 50.456102333333334, 30.479830833333335, 146.8000030517578
lat, lon, h = 50.456104833333335, 30.479832166666665, 146.60000610351562
enu = pm.geodetic2enu(lat, lon, h, lat0, lon0, h0)
print(enu)
(0.09468907882125363, 0.2781010036403331, -0.19999695501758974)
```

Can anyone please tell what is wrong here or if there's another method to calculate velocities.

Comment: Have you accounted for the curvature of the Earth in your calculations, or are assuming everything is horizontal?

Comment: Where's the time? You can't calculate the velocity between 2 points without knowing the time. Even then, your calculation would give the average velocity.  Perhaps the camera gives instantaneous velocity. You should check the camera instructions.